# How to minify automatically JavaScript and CSS in Astro (vs-code)

Tags: minify, astrojs

I am using Astro on VS-code and would like to find a way to automatically minify JavaScript and CSS files

I would like to minify the files in production when the build is launched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Astro already bundles and minifies a lot of the code but you can also use the [astro-compress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/astro-compress) integration to compress/minify your build further

You can also use post build processing tools for compression like:

- [Jampack](https://github.com/divriots/jampack)
- [Cloudflare Auto Minify](https://developers.cloudflare.com/support/speed/optimization-file-size/using-cloudflare-auto-minify/#overview)
- [Netlify Asset Optimization](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/file-based-configuration/#post-processing)
- and others

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the output of the `astro build` command, you should notice that the output is already minified to the best of Astro’s ability.